# Dynamically replace row in dataframe with vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame for example:

```
d <- read.table(text='   V1 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
1 1 a 2 3 4 9 6
2 1 b 2 2 4 5 NA
3 1 c 1 3 4 5 8
4 1 d 1 2 3 6 9
5 2 a 1 2 3 4 5
6 2 b 1 4 5 6 7
7 2 c 1 2 3 5 8
8 2 d 2 3 6 7 9', header=TRUE)
```

Now I want to take one row, for example the first one (1a) and:

1. Get the min and max value from that row. In this case min=2 and max=9 (note there are missing values in between for example there is no 5, 7, or 8 in that row).
2. Now I want to replace that row with all missing values and extend it (the row will be longer than all others as it will go from 2 until 9 (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).  The whole data.frame should then be automatically extended by NA columns for the other rows that are not as long as the one I replaced.

I tried a vector approach but I am pretty much stuck.  This is what I did so far:

```
vec.one_ <- d[1,]
vec.one <- as.vector(vec.one_[3:length(vec.one_)])
min.one <- min(vec.one, na.rm=T)
max.one <- max(vec.one, na.rm=T)
new.one <- as.numeric(vector(,length(vec.one)))
for(i in 1:length(new.one)){
  new.one[i] <- NA
}
```

I tried to extract the row as vector to manipulate it and then put it back in. I am not sure that works.

This should be the data.frame once the first row got replaced and the whole data.frame automatically extended with NAs:

```
d <- read.table(text='   V1 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7 V8 V9 V10
1 1 a 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 1 b 2 2 4 5 NA NA NA NA
3 1 c 1 3 4 5 8 NA NA NA
4 1 d 1 2 3 6 9 NA NA NA
5 2 a 1 2 3 4 5 NA NA NA
6 2 b 1 4 5 6 7 NA NA NA
7 2 c 1 2 3 5 8 NA NA NA
8 2 d 2 3 6 7 9 NA NA NA', header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to compute the new values for the row you want to change:

```
row.to.change <- 1
(new.row <- seq(min(d[row.to.change,c(-1, -2)], na.rm=TRUE), max(d[row.to.change,c(-1,-2)], na.rm=TRUE)))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Then I would extend out the data frame to the correct size:

```
(num.add <- length(new.row) - ncol(d) + 2)
# [1] 3
if (num.add > 0) {
  d <- cbind(d, replicate(num.add, rep(NA, nrow(d))))
} else if (num.add <= 0) {
  new.row <- c(new.row, rep(NA, -num.add))
}
```

Finally, I would replace the elements in the row of interest:

```
d[row.to.change,c(-1, -2)] <- new.row
d
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7  1  2  3
# 1  1  a  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
# 2  1  b  2  2  4  5 NA NA NA NA
# 3  1  c  1  3  4  5  8 NA NA NA
# 4  1  d  1  2  3  6  9 NA NA NA
# 5  2  a  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
# 6  2  b  1  4  5  6  7 NA NA NA
# 7  2  c  1  2  3  5  8 NA NA NA
# 8  2  d  2  3  6  7  9 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! To extend the data frame the +2 means you add them because you removed the first two columns earlier?

Comment: @LillyKuil you're replacing elements 3 and onward, so you don't count the first two columns in the current width.

Comment: Is it possible to count the headers in the same way as well? In your example the new columns have a new index 1,2,3 - would it be possible to make them V8 V9 V10? (depending on the number of new columns of course)?

Comment: @LillyKuil at the end you can just do `colnames(d) <- paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(d)))`

Comment: When I apply the following line to a data.frame that has 5000 columns : (new.row <- seq(min(d[row.to.change,c(-1, -2)]), max(d[row.to.change,c(-1,-2)]))) I get this error: Error in seq.default(min(d[row.to.change, c(-1, -2)]), max(d[row.to.change,  : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Comment: I think its because the particular row has many NAs at the end so I included: na.rm = T but then it missed the NAs later on in: results_raw[row.to.change,c(-1, -2)] <- new.row and produces: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, row.to.change, c(-1, -2), value = 10:200) : 
  replacement has 191 items, need 4998

Comment: @LillyKuil try now -- it sounds like you have a replacement that is too small in the last case.

Comment: How would you do that if you do the same thing just not with row 1 in the example but with row 2 (which has an NA at the end)?

Comment: No it just produces the error I mentioned: Error in seq.default(min(d[row.to.change, c(-1, -2)]), max(d[row.to.change,  : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Comment: @LillyKuil Unfortunately it's quite tough to debug in the comments on Stack Overflow. If possible please construct a small example that shows this error and then add it into your question.

Comment: Thank you, I think if you run the original example above just with row.to.change <- 2 then it should reproduce the error

Comment: @LillyKuil it works fine on my computer with `row.to.change <- 2`. Make sure you re-copy the original definition of `d` from the question and then all the lines of code from my answer.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! This does work for the row that I specify for example 2 or 1 how does this work, if for example I want it to work for all rows which have a 'b' in the second column? Something like: do this where d$V2 == 'b'? In case the data.frame is 5000 rows long running the snippet every time is not that advantageous.

Comment: @LillyKuil this site works best if you ask new questions with the "Ask Question" button instead of asking additional questions in the comments, because then the entire community will be notified of the question instead of just me.

Comment: done that here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094538/replace-the-rows-in-dataframe-with-condition